# facebook graph api place search more than one type in one request

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook graph api place search to get nearby places . 
in the docs is written to send these request to get data : 
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Restaurants&type=place&center=32.075267,34.774997&distance=600&access_token=

but i need to get not only Restaurants but also food,Clothing Store,bar and more categories but in one request . is it possible ?

Comment: In your request q=Restaurants doesn't refine categories, instead it will search for all the places which contain text as Restaurants. Do you need to search for every place nearby?

Comment: yes any suggestion?. meanwhile i'm trying search distance without the q parameter.

Comment: Correct, using the same api without q parameter will give you all the places nearby

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to search for **exclusive** keywords at once. Be aware that you can't even search for page categories as you seem to believe. The `/search` endpoint does a full text search on the respective object (page, place, event etc.).

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search